# No Route Matches error - with Nested Resource controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, nested

I have a problem with my application, crash when I put the path student_postulations_path in the navbar :S.

I have in my `route.rb`

```
resources :students do
    resources :postulations
  end
```

and my application say this error

```
No route matches {:controller=>"postulations"}
```

**My view**

```
<% elsif student_signed_in? %>
  <% menu_group :pull => :right do %>
    <%= menu_item "Postulaciones", student_postulations_path %>
    <%= menu_divider %>
    <%= drop_down current_student.email do %>
      <%= menu_item "Logout", destroy_student_session_path, :method => :delete %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
```

when I use rake routes:

```
student_postulations GET    /students/:student_id/postulations(.:format)          postulations#index
                           POST   /students/:student_id/postulations(.:format)          postulations#create
   new_student_postulation GET    /students/:student_id/postulations/new(.:format)      postulations#new
  edit_student_postulation GET    /students/:student_id/postulations/:id/edit(.:format) postulations#edit
       student_postulation GET    /students/:student_id/postulations/:id(.:format)      postulations#show
                           PUT    /students/:student_id/postulations/:id(.:format)      postulations#update
                           DELETE /students/:student_id/postulations/:id(.:format)      postulations#destroy
```

My models student and postulation:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :nombre, :rol,
                    :prioridad, :resumen, :categoria, :foto
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  has_many :postulations
end

class Postulation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :status, :student_id

  belongs_to :student
end
```

I dont understand my error... I thing have all right. Please help! :).

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In nested resource routing you are getting

```
student_postulations GET    /students/:student_id/postulations(.:format)
```

So in your view you need to pass the @student object with `student_postulations_path(@student)`

The helpers like `student_postulations_path`, `student_postulations_url` take an instance of Student as the first parameter `student_postulations_path(@student)` to find the record of student .

You can get more info from the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

So your link path will be

```
<%= menu_item "Postulaciones", student_postulations_path(current_student) %>
```

Comment: <%= menu_item "Postulaciones", student_postulations_path(current_student) %> Thank you ! :D! you fixed my error noob :) in 5 min ticket green ;)